# How should BPMN Messsage Flow be used in BPMN Simulations

Tags: simulation, enterprise-architect, bpmn

My (somewhat limited - I haven't been a serious practitioner in the past) understanding of BPMN was that you had to use Message Flows when transferring control between flow items in different Pools.  We built a non-trivial business process that followed this rule.  However, when we tried to run the Sparx Systems' EA simulation engine over that process, it would not get past the first Message Flow.

Is my understanding correct?  (You should use Message Flows and Not Sequence Flows between pools)
Why will the simulation work only if we convert ALL the Message Flows to Sequence Flows?

What is the best practice here?

Comment: You say _"message flows [for] transferring control flow between different pools"_. That is not what happens. Each pool has its own sequence flow. There can be an intermediate event in the sequence flow of one pool, waiting for a message to arrive. This way the two processes can synchronize their sequence flows. But a message flow never _transfers_ control to another pool.

I don't know how Enterprise Architect is simulating this, but your question makes me think, maybe you are missing some sequence flows?

Comment: Thanks, Axel; your comment bears out what I've subsequently found out about Enterprise Architect.  I now understand the point you're making.  EA uses a DIFFERENT simulation (BPSim) mechanism for handling Collaborations between Pools rather than sim[ple BPMN Sim for processes within the same pool.  I haven't been able to get the BPSim to work as I want yet, but at least I understand what's required.